# Fast way to check if postgis bounding box contains any points/linestrings

Tags: postgis, postgresql, query

I have a bounding box given and want to know if this bounding box contains (or better intersects) any points or linestrings. So the query should return true if the first point/linestring was found and not test all of them.

The query I got so far is this:

```
SELECT NOT 
 (ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(13.3277368531, 52.4783729748), ST_Point(13.463715857, 52.5520736045)), 4326), 3857), geom_vertex_web_mercator) 
AND 
 ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(13.3277368531, 52.4783729748), ST_Point(13.463715857, 52.5520736045)), 4326), 3857), geom_way_web_mercator)) as isEmpty 
FROM vertex, edge 
LIMIT 1;
```

But this just takes the first point/linestring and returns the value for it. Can any one help.

**EDIT**
This query seems to be very fast:

```
select exists (select true from network where ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(-140.0, 80.0), ST_Point(-135.0, 80.0)), 4326), 3857), geom_way_web_mercator)) as isEmpty;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [`SELECT EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-subquery.html)? According to the docs it should run until the first (if any) row is returned.